# Calculate type counts and add types separated by commas to a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataframe like this,

```
ID <- c("ID001","ID001","ID001","ID002","ID002","ID002")
ToolID <- c("SWP","SWP","SWP","ISP","ISP","ISP")
Type <- c("A","B","C","D","E","A")
WHEN <- c("2017-08-15 12:44:11","2017-08-15 12:44:11","2017-08-14 19:07:11",
          "2017-08-17 11:24:15","2017-08-17 11:24:15","2017-08-17 11:24:15")

df <- data.frame(ID,ToolID,Type,WHEN) 
df$WHEN <- as.POSIXct(df$WHEN,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I am trying to put all the types in one column separated by commas and also calculate the count for the ID's grouped by (Tool_ID & ID) while only taking the MAX(WHEN), the recent time stamp for the respective ID.

My **desired output** is

```
     ID ToolID  Type Type_count                WHEN
  ID001    SWP   A,B          2 2017-08-15 12:44:11
  ID002    ISP D,E,A          3 2017-08-17 11:24:15
```

I tried using data.table and did it this way

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, WHEN := as.POSIXct(WHEN)]
df1 <- df[, max(WHEN), by = list(ID,ToolID)]
colnames(df1 )[which(names(df1 ) == "V1")] <- "WHEN"
```

How do I get the types and types count added to df1 to get my desired output? 
Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a rowindex based on the logical condition, then use the group by, specify the index in `i` and get the summary

```
i1 <- setDT(df)[, .I[WHEN == max(WHEN)], .(ID, ToolID)]$V1
df[i1, .(Type = toString(unique(Type)), Type_count = uniqueN(Type),
         WHEN = WHEN[1]), .(ID, ToolID)]
#      ID ToolID    Type Type_count                WHEN
#1: ID001    SWP    A, B          2 2017-08-15 12:44:11
#2: ID002    ISP D, E, A          3 2017-08-17 11:24:15
```